# com.sun.star.uno does not exists error

Tags: java, import, classpath, openoffice.org, uno

hi i was referring the following document for Web-based spreadsheets with OpenOffice.org and Dojo

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2008/jw-05-spreadsheets.html?page=1

I am developing such thing for first time..

I created the java classes but when i compile the class 'SpreadsheetDoc.java' i get the following error :

```
com.sun.star.uno does not exists
```

I may be skipping some step by mistake dont know what.
tried setting the class path for `openoffice/program` folder but still getting problem

I am using apache tomcat 7.0, Open office 3, JDK 6.

How can i get the proper import for the namespace.

```
com.sun.star.uno
```

I think that it could be some problem related to

```
juh.jar
jurt.jar
ridl.jar
unoil.jar
```

reference but not sure...

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the OpenOffice SDK?

Comment: Thanks for the help. didn't knew this thing as i am developing first time for open office

Comment: still giving the same problem. even after installing the sdk. do i need to do something additional after sdk instal...